# discord.client: logging in using static token help me

Tags: python, discord

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzyUu.png)

Code:

```py
import discord
import os
import sys
import asyncio
import time
import json

from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='*', intents=discord.Intents.all())
TOKEN= 'ODU1MDAwMzU3Njk2NDM4MzEy.Gxtt2S.IxUbC9bS8Ps3hTeUYpwxW_U7A6q0MuzTwJxUFA'

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(" Bot account ")
    print()
    print(f"Username: {bot.user.name}")
    print(f"Bot ID: {bot.user.id}")
    print(f"Bot token: {TOKEN}")
    print()

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: It looks like you might have accidentally shared your bot's secret token, please invalidate it if you do not want your bot to be abused by third parties.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is throwing an `discord.errors.PrivilegedIntentsRequired` Exception as you can see in the bottom line of your screenshot.

This means it is trying to use intents that it has no permission to use. Either enable those intents in the discord developer portal or replace `discord.Intents.all()` with the intents that you really need and have sufficient permissions for.